# How to compute 2D cumulative sum efficiently

Tags: python, performance, numpy, probability, cdf

Given a two-dimensional numerical array `X` of shape `(m,n)`, I would like to compute an array `Y` of the same shape, where `Y[i,j]` is the cumulative sum of `X[i_,j_]` for `0<=i_<=i, 0<=j_<=j`. If `X` describes a 2D probability distribution, `Y` could be thought of as the 2D cumulative distribution function (CDF).

I can obviously compute all entries of `Y` in a double `for` loop. However, there is a recursive aspect to this computation, as `Y[i,j] = X[i,j] + Y[i-1,j] + Y[i,j-1] - Y[i-1,j-1]` (where negative indexing means 0).

I was looking for "2d Python cumsum", and I've found that NumPy's `cumsum` merely flattens the array.

**My Questions:**

1. Is there a standard Python function for computing `Y` efficiently?
2. If not, is the recursive idea above optimal?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like your approach for the 2d cumulative sum is workable. However, I wonder what is the larger goal you are working towards. If you need joint probabilities, or conditional probabilities, the 2d cumulative sum might not be coming into the picture, and some other calculation might be needed.

Comment: @RobertDodier This problem arose from a coding question involving all square subarray sums of an array. I thought that having the cumulative sums from the upper-left corner could help speeding things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **kernel splitting** method can be applied here to solve this problem very efficiently with only two `np.cumsum`: one vertical and one horizontal (or the other way since this is symmetric).

Here is an example:

```py
x = np.random.randint(0, 10, (4, 5))
print(x)
y = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(x, axis=0), axis=1)
print(y)
```

Here is the result:

```
[[1 9 8 1 7]
 [0 6 8 2 3]
 [1 3 6 4 4]
 [0 8 1 2 9]]

[[ 1 10 18 19 26]
 [ 1 16 32 35 45]
 [ 2 20 42 49 63]
 [ 2 28 51 60 83]]
```